# Javassist: check if object is proxy

Tags: java, proxy, javassist

I'm using `javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory` to create some proxies in my project. And in some other part of the code I would like to be able to check if an object is proxied or not.

So my question is: is there a way to check if an object is a proxy or not?

For instance, I have a class User and when I make a proxy object of it, in debugger it's class is `User_$$_javassist_11`. Is there something analogous to `instanceof` which I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like [ProxyFactory.isProxyClass](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/util/proxy/ProxyFactory.html#isProxyClass%28java.lang.Class%29)?

Comment: Thanks. I saw that method, but it was throwing an exception for me java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.isProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z so I thought there is another way. But, obviously, I have some other problem in my app. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nikola - yes, that indicates that you have the wrong jars on your runtime classpath.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My other dependency references an older version of javassist and thus the error message.